# Limiting the number of iterations in Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf, stanford-parser

I am training the Stanford NER CRF model, on a customised dataset but the number of iterations that is being used to train the model have now gone to 
333 iterations-i.e. and this training process has now gone for hours.
Below is the message printed in the terminal -

```
Iter 335 evals 400 <D> [M 1.000E0] 2.880E3 38054.87s |5.680E1| {6.652E-6} 4.488E-4 - 
Iter 336 evals 401 <D> [M 1.000E0] 2.880E3 38153.66s |1.243E2| {1.456E-5} 4.415E-4 -
 -
```

The properties file being used is given below - is there some way I can limit the number of iterations to say 20.

```
location of the training file
trainFile = TRAIN5000.tsv
#location where you would like to save (serialize to) your
#classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
#making it faster and smaller
serializeTo = ner-model_TRAIN5000.ser.gz

#structure of your training file; this tells the classifier
#that the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in
#column 1
map = word=0,answer=1

#these are the features we'd like to train with
#some are discussed below, the rest can be
#understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
#no ngrams will be included that do not contain either the
#beginning or end of the word
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
#the next 4 deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
saveFeatureIndexToDisk = true
printFeatures=true
flag useObservedSequencesOnly=true
featureDiffThresh=0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with training a biomedical (BioNER) model via the `Stanford CoreNLP CRF classifier` on IOB-tagged, tokenized text as described at https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html.

My corpus -- from downloaded sources -- was very large (~1.5M lines; 6 features: GENE; ...).  As the training seemed to run indefinitely, I plotted the ratio of the Values to get an idea of the progress:

[image: plot of ratio of CRF training Values per Iteration]

Grepping the Java source code, I found that the default `TOL` (`tolerance`; used to decide when to terminate the training session) value was 1E-6 (0.000001), specified in `.../CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/QNMinimizer.java`.

Looking at that plot, my original training session would never have completed.  [That plot also shows that setting a larger `TOL` value, e.g. `tolerance=0.05`, will trigger a premature termination of the training, as that `TOL` value is triggered by the "noise" that occurs near the beginning of the training session. I confirmed this with a `tolerance=0.05` entry in my `.prop` file; however, `TOL` values of `0.01`, `0.005` etc. were "OK."]

Adding the "`maxIterations=20`" to the properties file as described by @StanfordNLPHelp (elsewhere in this thread) appeared to be ignored unless I also added and changed the `tolerance=` value, in my `bioner.prop` properties file; e.g.

```
tolerance=0.005
maxIterations=20    ## optional
```

in which case the classifier quickly trained the model (`bioner.ser.gz`).  [When I added the `maxIterations` line to my `.prop` file, without adding the `tolerance` line, the model just kept running "forever," as before.]

A list of parameters that can be included in the `.prop` file can be found here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html

Comment: How do we use the generated model to make our own predictions? It's not mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use `tolerance` (defaults to 1e-4). There's another parameter `maxIterations` which is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxQNItr=21` in your prop file. It will run upto 20 iterations. Got help from [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235658/4595807)

Answer (score -1):

Add `maxIterations=20` to the properties file.

Comment: maxIterations is not used. It's neither part of the call nor the construction of the minimizer.